# How would I use gstreamer to stitch a set of images together to form a video slideshow

Tags: c, video, audio, gstreamer, vala

I'd like to take a set of images and a sound track and use that to form a basic video slideshow using gstreamer.

There seems to be a lot of documentation and examples of basic gstreamer usage like playing a video or audio file, or even transcoding and the like. But I can't seem to find anything particularly useful for, I suppose, video editing tasks.

I feel that I have a decent grasp of the fundamentals of gstreamer, but I'm having trouble conceptualising how I would join the dots, so to speak. Specifically the bit where I take a set of images and turn them into a single video output.

Comment: Du you want to render the slideshow to a video or just us gstreamer to display the pictures and display the slide show in your application?

Comment: I figured what happens at that end of the pipeline is irrelevant. The end purpose would be to write it out to a file, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pitivi.

If you want to write the program anyway you should use gnonlin, the library pitivi is built upon. You would be putting together a gnlcompositon. See also http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/PyGST_Tutorial

Comment: Apparently gnonlin has undergone a total documentation failure.

Comment: The most useful resources for me were Jono Bacon's blog posts on gnonlin and the source code to the webcam program Cheese.

Comment: I cannot see how this is answering precisely the "use gstreamer" part of the question? Is pitivi gstreamer?

Answer (score 11):

The module MultiFileSrc will do that for you.

From [the doc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multifilesrc.html)

> The multifilesrc element is used to read a collection of sequentially named files, e.g., 00001.jpg, 00002.jpg, 00003.jpg, etc., into a GStreamer pipeline.
>
> == Example Pipeline ==
>
> This pipeline reads the files 00001.png, 00002.png, etc., decodes them, and then reencodes the video into Ogg/Theora.
>
> gst-launch multifilesrc location=%05d.png \
>     caps="image/png,framerate=30/1,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1" ! \
>     pngdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)I420 ! \
>     theoraenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=output.ogg

Comment: I like that this answer actually uses gstreamer gst-launch. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Images Slideshow in Gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952955/images-slideshow-in-gstreamer/4055359#4055359)

try this for an alternative solution. Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to write a program? I think you should check out [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for making a video by providing a set of images. Its cross platform and hence may suit your need.

I hope it helps.

If you want related to gstreamer library then you can check out source code of various gstreamer based open source applications [here](http://www.gstreamer.net/apps/).